# How to create a Blockchain for new alt coin after genesis block has been created?

Tags: altcoin-development

I am creating a new alt coin and I want to know how to generate a Blockchain for that coin. I have already created the genesis block for my new alt coin.

Comment: What's the block generation mechanism? Proof-of-work? Proof-of-stake? Something else? Please post the parameters for your altcoin, otherwise, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Iam suing Scrypt-Adaptive-Nfactor

Comment: Are you mining yet? What error messages do you get when you try?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following steps:

bitcoind -daemon # Start bitcoin core

bitcoin-cli setgenerate true 1 # You've started a new miner!!

tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log # Track your log

After a while (it depends on the difficulty of your altcoin), a new block will be generated by your miner.

Check it by typing "bitcoin-cli getblockcount". Every time a new block is genereated, the value increases by one.

Comment: hi @moshaholo i'm trying to execute this command "bitcoin-cli setgenerate true 1" but i was removed in the new versions, do you know how can i get first block with recently litecoin source?. thanks

Answer (score -2):

If you're using some form of Proof-of-Work, i believe you have to generate enough transactions that can fill a block. Of course that 1st block will refer to the genesys block. Then other transactions will fill a 2nd block, that will refer to the 1st. And so on.

And voilá, you have the blockchain.

Good luck with your altcoin.